# Calculating brownian motion in Eulers method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, brownian-motion, eulers-method

Say for example we have brownian motion term added to an expression $W(t)$ and our $t=2$, what would $W(2)$ be?

I' ve tried searching the internet but I can't seem to find a way that gives a formula or anything...

I have this together with an ODE, which I have to solve using the Euler's method.

$$y_1 = y_0 + hf(t_n, y_n) + \frac{W(t_{n+1}) - W(t_n)}{t_{n+1}-t_n}$$

Where $f(t, y(t) = y(t)$, $y_0 = y(1) = 4$

Comment: You might be looking for something like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maruyama_method which has a numerical example which might be useful.

Comment: I can't make sense of your first sentence sorry.

Comment: If $W(t)$ is Brownian Motion and the increrment in t is h, then $W(t+h)-W(t)$ is a random variable with mean 0 and variance h